# Fix image to right of centered text without moving the text

Tags: html, css, position

From this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uuvLogcr/1/) you can see that if you press the 'toggle circle' button the circle which is inline with the text hides and shows. The text beside it moves as well because the `div` surrounding it centers the text using `text-align: center;`

```js
function hide() {
  $('img').toggle();
}
```

```css
div {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: grey;
  padding: 20px;
}
p {
  display: inline;
  color: white;
  vertical-align: top;
}
img {
  display: inline;
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="hide();">Toggle Circle</button>

<div>
  <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/13/Disc_Plain_red.svg">
</div>
```

I would like it so that the text is centered as if the circle is not there and then when the button is clicked the circle appears alongside it. Put simply I would like the centering of the text to not be affected by the circle even though it will still appear next to it.

How would I do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can edit the markup, move `<img>` into `<p>`, then set it as `img {position:absolute;}` to take it out of the normal content flow. And use `top`, `right` values along with `transform` to put the image into correct place.

Updated - https://jsfiddle.net/uuvLogcr/5/

```js
function hide() {
  $('img').toggle();
}
```

```css
div {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: grey;
  padding: 20px;
}
p {
  display: inline;
  color: white;
  position: relative;
}
img {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(100%, -50%);
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="hide();">Toggle Circle</button>

<div>
  <p>
    Lorem Ipsum
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/13/Disc_Plain_red.svg">
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do this with `relative/absolute` position so `img` doesn't affect natural flow of elements

```js
function hide() {
  $('img').toggle();
}
```

```css
.content {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: grey;
  padding: 20px;
}

.inner {
  position: relative;
  display: inline;
}

p {
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  vertical-align: top;
}

img {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  right: -50px;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="hide();">Toggle Circle</button>

<div class="content">
  <div class="inner">
    <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/13/Disc_Plain_red.svg">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in a simpler way.

By using `visibility:` with `hidden` or `visible` (instead of `display`, which jQuery `toggle` uses), the element's space is still "reserved"
You can then use jQuery `toggleClass`, and adding a class that toggles `visibility`.

Doing it this way, you don't have to calculate positions like you would with `position: absolute`

I've updated your fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/uuvLogcr/3/

Updated jQuery:

```
function hide() {
    $('img').toggleClass('hidden');
}
```

Updated CSS:

```
div {
text-align: center;
background-color: grey;
padding: 20px;
}

p {
  display: inline;
  color: white;
  vertical-align: top;
}

img {
  display: inline;
  width: 50px;
  visibility: visible;
}

img.hidden {
   visibility: hidden;
}
```